# Free postgres hosting for testing

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

Does anybody use a free postgres host to test applications? I am trying to test my webapp that uses hibernate trying to connect to a remote postgres server; I currently have it setup using my postgres server on localhost and am having trouble connecting to a remote host and would like to see if it is working on another (hopefully free) postgres host.

I am having no luck with google and have signed up for a few things so far only to get to a point where I need to buy a period of hosting.

Comment: Heroku has free Postgres hosting if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: But I don't think anyone is offering "exposed to the internet" PostgreSQL hosting. Why not just have your host connect back to your office/home and throw up a copy of PG there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, a Postgres installation cannot accept remote connections. You need to configure them.

You need to edit pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files in the Postgres 
installation directory.

The pg_hba.conf is used to specify network access, and the postgresql.conf is for all other settings, in which you'll need to specify IP address to listen to.

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html for a nice clear tutorial.

Comment: +1 from me; absolutely correct.  But even if this is done, I doubt that it'll be exposed directly to the Internet.  There should be one or two firewalls separating the database from the Internet.  Firewall rules will have to be set up to access the database port.

Answer (score 1):

> trouble connecting to a remote host

What are the symptoms?  What error message do you get when you try to connect?  Maybe you have to contact the owner of that Postgres server to make sure you can access it.

If it's behind a firewall - and I sincerely hope that it is - you'll need to make special provisions to be able to access it.

If it's just exposed to the Internet, for anyone to access, I'd caution you against putting any data in it that you could not afford to lose.